# Publish Windows Forms Application - Where do Images go?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

A real R101 question on Windows Forms.

I have created my first Windows application to print invoices. I have one image which is the company logo (png). The app works great in VS2010 when debugging - I placed the image in the the bin folder.

Now I have published it and installed it on another machine I get this exception error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: ice-logo-bw.png

So the question is where do I place the image so it gets included when I publish? I have tried putting it in the root folder with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include the image in the project - possibly under a folder of its own with other images.

You should then set the [Build Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx) on this image - right click, select properties and select "Copy if Newer" or "Copy always".

An alternative is to add it as a resource, but this means you need to also fetch it from the resources rather than the filesystem.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. I've created a folder and placed images in it but I cant see the images. When I placed the images in the root I thought it was odd that I couldn't see them despite refreshing. The files are there in windows explorer

Comment: @ComfortablyNumb - You need to add the images to the project. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92.aspx

Comment: All works great apart from running it as a scheduled task where I get the same error. The only difference I can see is that the scheduled task goes directly to the application exe whereas the application icon points to the click one application. Any ideas?

Comment: @ComfortablyNumb - Perhaps try to set the working directory for the scheduled job to be the exe directory.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said you need to make sure that when you deploy / install your application to another machine that your image files are also copied - the most suitable place is probably the output directory of your project (the `bin/` directory where the compiled `.exe` goes) - you can set the "Copy to Output Directory" property for the files to be "Copy if newer" to have Visual Studio do this automatically for you.

Another thing to consider is how you load your images - if you are using relative paths then you might find that your program fails to find your image even if they are present alongside your executable because the working directory is different, try running your program from the command prompt on your development machine to see this happening:

```
:: Make sure that the current working directory is different from the one app.exe is in
C:\> path\to\my\program\app.exe
```

If your code looks a little like this:

```
var image = LoadImage("myfile.png");
```

Then this will probably fail because your program is looking for the image at `c:\myfile.png` instead of `C:\path\to\my\program\app.exe`.  You should modify your code to look a little like this:

---

Another alternative would be to use [embedded resources](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292).  This is slightly more complex however has the advantage that your images are embedded into the output .exe itself - no additional files are needed so it reduces the chances that required files can't be found because they have been deleted / moved / weren't copied during installation.

```
string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "myfile.png");
var image = LoadImage(path);
```

Comment: thanks for that. This explains why I'm having problems running the exe through scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not place case (where you put the files) but `Build Action` & `Copy to OutputDirectory` properties - can be accesed in properties window (Visual Studio).
After added files (images) to project set following properties:

```
Build Action = None (depend on your application)
Copy to Output Directory  = Copy always
```

Documentation reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx).

Comment: Please try to link to the _latest_ version of the documentation.

Comment: Of Course - next time i'll remember to check. Thx.